# Amazon SNS Push Service - used for friends request in android app

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I have a question concerning the design of my app. I have different users, which I want to socially bound as friends. This requires a proper notification for the other user as well as accepting the request.

My question is how to do it with AWS? I have users stored in Cognito Identity Pool. Should I use push notifications informing the user about friend request? If so, how to send a push notification from one android device to the other?

If not, how else should I design it? And if I want to implement notifications inside the App is Push service still valid (encoding by Lambda, something like this?) or should I use something different?

Kind regards,

Grzegorz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you don’t want your app to have permissions to send push notifications directly to other devices. Assuming you have each users device tokens, using a Lambda function as you mentioned to send an SNS push notification to the potential friend's device which could then trigger a flow which could allow them to accept and link as friends (depending on how your friend flow works).

You can find some helpful SNS documentation at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html. Mobile Hub can help you get started quickly, and will create an app that can receive push notifications, and trig (https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobilehub). You can also use Mobile Hub to add Lambda to your mobile app.